# Convert Python object to C void type

Tags: python, c, cython

How can I convert Python object to C void type using Cython?

Currently I am getting this message when I try to cast

Casting temporary Python object to non-numeric non-Python type

Comment: Why not just use the underlying `PyObject*`?

Comment: I presume you mean `void*`, not `void`.

Answer (score 10):

This can be done like this :

**1. Cast from Python to C**

If you really meant `void *` this would be :

```
some_pyobj = "abc"
cdef void *ptr
ptr = <void *>some_pyobj
```

If you meant `PyObject *` this would be :

```
cdef PyObject *ptr
ptr = <PyObject *>some_pyobj           # Cast from Python object to C pointer
```

Then, from C side, the `PyObject struct` is available by including `Python.h`.

Here is the reference (from `object.h` Python include file) :

```
/* Nothing is actually declared to be a PyObject, but every pointer to
 * a Python object can be cast to a PyObject*.  This is inheritance built
 * by hand.  Similarly every pointer to a variable-size Python object can,
 * in addition, be cast to PyVarObject*.
 */
typedef struct _object {
    PyObject_HEAD
} PyObject;
```

**2. Cast from C to Python**

It works in both ways, meaning that the following is also possible :

```
cdef PyObject *ptr
ptr = <PyObject *>some_pyobj
cdef object some_other_pyobj
some_other_pyobj = <object>ptr          # Cast from C pointer to Python object
```

Answer (score 1):

You can:

```
def run():
   pyobj = 'abc'
   pyobj_void_star = <void *>pyobj
```