# cython convert void* back to python obj

Tags: python, c, cython

Got error message while want to convert void* back to python obj.

Based on this article
[Convert Python object to C void type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16907168/convert-python-object-to-c-void-type)
the conversion should be easy.

```
struct _node {
    void * data;
} node;

cpdef match(self, path):
    m = cpyr3.r3_tree_match(self.root, path, NULL)

    if m:
        return <object>m.data
```

## Error Message:

```
Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...

    cpdef match(self, path):
        m = cpyr3.r3_tree_match(self.root, path, NULL)

        if m:
            return <object>m.data
                           ^
------------------------------------------------------------

cpyr3.pyx:18:28: Cannot convert 'node *' to Python object
```

## I tested several ways:

### 1.

```
Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
        cpyr3.r3_tree_compile(self.root, NULL)

    cpdef match(self, path):
        m = cpyr3.r3_tree_match(self.root, path, NULL)
        if m:
            return <object>(m.data[0])
                            ^
------------------------------------------------------------

cpyr3.pyx:17:29: Cannot convert 'node *' to Python object
```

### 2.

this one will pass compile, but raise exception in runtime

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 22, in <module>
    print run(r)
  File "test.py", line 13, in run
    return r.match('/foo/bar')
  File "cpyr3.pyx", line 14, in pyr3.R3Tree.match (cpyr3.c:1243)
    cpdef match(self, path):
  File "cpyr3.pyx", line 17, in pyr3.R3Tree.match (cpyr3.c:1186)
    return <object>(m[0].data[0])
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'data'
```

where the dict come from?

## EDIT2: to reproduce the issue (with details):

Source repo: https://github.com/lucemia/pyr3/tree/cython

```
git clone https://github.com/lucemia/pyr3/ -b cython 
cd pyr3
rm cpyr3.c
rm pyr3.c
git submodule init; git submodule update; 
cd r3
./autogen.sh
./configure
cd ..
python setup_cython.py build_ext --inplace
```

## EDIT3:

change the cpyr3.pxd 
from

```
cdef extern from "r3.h":
    ctypedef struct node:
        pass
```

to

```
cdef extern from "r3.h":
    ctypedef struct node:
        void *data
```

fix the issue!

Comment: There's some important details missing from your question, but perhaps it's because the `return` expression is being evaluated left-to-right like this `(<object>m).data`.

Comment: Thx for response, I tried <object>(m.data) but got the same results. the complete repo can be viewed at: 
https://github.com/lucemia/pyr3/tree/cython

Comment: How about `<object>(m.data[0])`? It's confusing that the error is "Cannot convert 'node *'" rather than "Cannot convert 'void *'". Note that `m` is a `node *`, the return value of `r3_tree_match()`.

Comment: I tried `git clone -b cython ...; git submodule init; git submodule update; python setup_cython.py build_ext --inplace` and I got no descriptive error at all (`gcc [...etc...] -std=c99` `cpyr3.c:1:2: error: #error Do not use this file, it is the result of a failed Cython compilation.`). You should give more detailed instructions.

Comment: @Veedrac update with detailed instructions .. please check

Comment: Yup, that solved it. It was the third possibility that I gave. Answer updated.

Comment: Many thanks, really hard to find the cause. I didn't find doc mentioned about this behaviour!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested

```
cdef struct _node:
    void * data
ctypedef _node node

cpdef pack_unpack():
    cdef node my_node = node(<void *>"some object")

    # This is what should be returned
    cdef node *m = &my_node
    return <object>m.data
```

with

```
import pyximport
pyximport.install()

import c_unpacker
print(c_unpacker.pack_unpack())
```

and it worked completely fine.

So my answer is that something else is probably happening. It would help if I had a minimal runnable sample I could test.

Three possible errors to check:

- `m` is untyped or incorrectly typed
- `self.root` or `path` are the wrong types
- `_node` is incorrectly typed. For example, with `cdef struct _node: pass` I get

  ```
  Error compiling Cython file:
  ------------------------------------------------------------
  ...
  cpdef pack_unpack():
      cdef node my_node = node(<void *>"some object")

      # This is what should be returned
      cdef node *m = &my_node
      return <object>m.data
                     ^
  ------------------------------------------------------------

  c_unpacker.pyx:10:20: Cannot convert 'node *' to Python object
  ```

  This happens because `m` does not have the attribute `data` according to the bad definition that Cython sees. Cython defaults to casting to a Python type in these scenarios.

---

Going through the compilation steps, I managed to work out that you have

```
cdef extern from "r3.h":
    ctypedef struct node:
        pass
```

this is the third point on my list. You should change that to

```
cdef extern from "r3.h":
    ctypedef struct node:
        void *data
```

This removes that error.

Comment: thx, the runable repo can be viewed at: https://github.com/lucemia/pyr3/tree/cython

Comment: the exception will raise after I execute `python setup_cython.py build_ext --inplace`